# Preemption in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, real-time

I am applying real time patch to the linux vanilla kernel.
I osadl website recommends kernel version 2.6.33 but it was written in 2010
https://www.osadl.org/Latest-Stable-Realtime.latest-stable-realtime-linux.0.html

As I have read linux kernel 3.x have better preemption by default. Which one is better for real time application?
Should I use kernel 3.x with rt patch?

Answer (score 1):

All the most up to date Linux RT patches are here: http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/

For a new project I'd use the latest Linux 3.0 because it is the "long term support" kernel version. It will be maintained for (at least) two years.